# 'Resource' object has no attribute '__getitem__' - Soundcloud Oembed

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to embed a track using Soundcloud API but I keep getting:

**'Resource' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

The issue is in the embed_info['html'] but I don't know how to fix it.

```
def downloadgate(request):
    # create a client object with your app credentials
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='Client_id')
    # get a tracks oembed data
    track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/daomusic/preview'
    embed_info = client.get('/oembed', url=track_url)
    embed_info = embed_info['html']
    # print the html for the player widget
    return render(request, 'rango/downloadgate.html', {'embed_info' : embed_info})
```